# Browser downloads are extremely slow

Tags: performance, browser, download

I'm trying to download [ProTeXt-3.1.3-060313.exe](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/systems/windows/protext/).

When I use my browsers to download it, it downloads about 20KB/s.

Than I found torrent file of the same program. I'm downloading it with 1.7MB/s now.
What causes my browsers to behave like this?

I tried IE, Chrome and Firefox. All the same.

**Edit:** It starts with 600KB/s but drops to 20KB/s in seconds.

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you download other files from different websites?

Comment: Yes, same thing happens.

Comment: Did you try restarting your router? If you have downloaded from the same domain, there is a chance that they are limiting your bandwidth.